# How to check for directory "reachability' by samba?

Tags: server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I am desperately trying to expose some shares so that they can be opened without any credentials. I do not care about the security of the data within (and of the whole server, so if it is easier to access them as `root` - this is very much fine with me).

There are plenty of HOWTOs on that subject, most of them contradictory (or for older version of samba, I use `4.5.8` on `xenial`)

With the following configuration (concatenated from various sources)

```
[2TB]
        comment = temporary dir
        path = /mnt/2TB
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        public = yes
        only guest = yes


[data]
    path = /var/lib/machines/tor/root/data
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    public = yes
    only guest = yes
```

I see on my Windows machines two shares when accessing `\\10.10.10.254` (the samba server).

One of the shares (`2TB`) is available (I see the contents) and access to the other one is denied with `You do not have permission to acces \\10.10.10.254\data`.

I suppose that the reason is due to access rights.

I `chmod` the `data` directory to 777 hoping that samba would get the hint (and not take into account the path components, which may not be accessible to the anonymous user). It did not solve the issue.

Any of the solutions below would be fine in my context (I am aware of all the bad things which can happen because of lax access rights, possibly with a privileged user - this is not a problem)

- the anonymous user is mapped to `root` and therefore has no restrictions to access the data
- access to the data is set up in such a way that `nobody` can access it

**What would be the correct configuration incantation (in `[global]` and the share definition) so one or both of the solutions above are enabled?**

Answer (score 1):

two ideas:
both related to the path of the second share:

`/var` is a system path (which is sometimes on a seperate temporary partition)

And if you want access to `/var/lib/machines/tor/root/data` you need to

`chmod -R 777` when you in directory `/var/lib/machines/tor/root/`

My proposal: make a new symbolic link in `/mnt`

`ln -s /var/lib/machines/tor/root/data /mnt/data` and try to share that one

Answer (score 1):

You can also try adding `force` commands to `samba.conf`

```
force user = [yourusername]
force group = [yourusername]
```

if that fits your use case